# How to implement a thread safe class queue 's push and pop method using c #

Tags: c#, multithreading

Following instruction from a great [article](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_WaitHandle_Producer_Consumer_Queue), I came to problem which I need to solve. How to implement a thread safe class queue's push and pop method?

Comment: Use [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Or (for .Net 4.5+) use [`BufferBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228601%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple lock would do just fine.

```
var synchro = new object();
var queue = new Queue<int>();
lock(synchro)
{
    queue.Enqueue(123); // Add to queue
}
lock(synchro)
{
    var num = queue.Dequeue(); // Remove from queue
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) in combination with a [`BlockingCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx), but it's less flexible. For example you can't safely add or remove multiple items at the same time.

Comment: @Neijwiert Because, *speaking from personal experience*, more often than not it won't be enough. It doesn't provide enough functionality *(as of .NET 4.6)*, and if you need it, you'll be in a world of hurt when you need to rewrite it. Better start off flexible.